# SQL Server evaluate all then part of case when

Tags: sql, sql-server

I create this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ml.fn_Temp() 
RETURNS @ResultTable TABLE (Code int) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Id int = (select 1 / 0)
    RETURN 
END
```

I run this query:

```
DECLARE @AccFieldKindName int = 9

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN @AccFieldKindName = 7 
            THEN (SELECT Code FROM ml.fn_Temp())
        WHEN @AccFieldKindName = 9 
            THEN 67777
    END
```

I get an error:

> Divide by zero error encountered

I think this is not correct to run code that its condition is not true.

Why does SQL run all the query? In reality `ml.fn_Temp` is a heavy query. In each run, SQL runs this function and that causes performance problems.

Can I change this behaviour, to run only part of `case when` with a condition that is true? I don't want to change this query to *If ... else* .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very much expected.

A non correlated multi statement TVF **always** executes before the query that references it and populates the table variable of results.

There is a sequence operator that runs that first and the rest of the plan afterwards. So the error is encountered  before execution of the `CASE` even begins

[image]

EDIT: There is one exception to the **always** actually `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` allows the `CASE` expression to be evaluated at compile time rather than run time and the reference to the TVF is entirely removed from the plan.

Your demo code is not realistic but maybe that will work for you? Otherwise maybe you could use an inline table valued function instead in your actual scenario.

Or use a local table variable/temp table prior to executing the query to conditionally call the function when needed

```
DECLARE @AccFieldKindName INT = 9
DECLARE @fn_Temp TABLE
  (
     Code INT
  );

IF @AccFieldKindName = 7
  BEGIN
      INSERT @fn_Temp
             (Code)
      SELECT Code
      FROM   dbo.fn_Temp()
  END

SELECT CASE
         WHEN @AccFieldKindName = 7 THEN (SELECT MIN(Code) FROM   @fn_Temp)
         WHEN @AccFieldKindName = 9 THEN 67777
       END
```